# Get an exact string from a file between one of three characters in KSH

Tags: regex, ksh

I need to check whether a file contains an exact string, say `string12345`, but not `string123456` for example. This string can contain spaces! The file consists of various rows that all need to be checked.

But the string can be in a different place on the row, between dividing characters. The dividing characters can be either `|` or `,`. Finally, the string can also be at the start or end of the row.

The check per row I have working so far is:

```
sLineFromFile=$(cat "${fFileToCheck}" | grep ^${sStringToCheck},)
```

So if `sLineFromFile` is not empty, I know the file (`fFileToCheck`) contains `sStringToCheck`, but only at the start of the line `^` and when followed by a comma `,`.

I'm looking then for some kind of `OR` feature like this:

```
sLineFromFile=$(cat "${fFileToCheck}" | grep [^,|]${sStringToCheck}[,|$])
```

I thought that this would work based on this [Unix & Linux SE link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22931/match-regex-in-ksh) but instead it appears to take the characters literally as written (so `sLineFromFile` is always empty). I have tried many variations including:

```
sLineFromFile=$(cat "${fFileToCheck}" | grep @[^,|]${sStringToCheck},)
sLineFromFile=$(cat "${fFileToCheck}" | grep (^,|)${sStringToCheck},)
sLineFromFile=$(cat "${fFileToCheck}" | grep '[^,|]${sStringToCheck},')
sLineFromFile=$(cat "${fFileToCheck}" | grep [^,|]${sStringToCheck},)
```

(here just testing the character before `sStringToCheck`).

How should I correct this?

Comment: Many [cats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) were harmed in the production of this question... `grep <pattern> <file>` is a good thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options :

1. If *stringToCheck* contains only the word characters(alphanumeric+underscore), you can use:

   ```
    grep -w "$stringToCheck" file
   ```
2. Otherwise, use the following :

   ```
    grep -E "(^|[\|,])$stringToCheck([\|,]|$)" file
   ```

I think this should solve your problem.

Again instead of getting the whole matched line, you can achieve the same using something like :

```
c=$(grep -Ec "(^|[\|,])$stringToCheck([\|,]|$)" file)
if [ $c -eq 0 ]
then
echo noMatch
else
echo hasMatch
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem with the first one is that `sStringToCheck` can contain *spaces*! I will update the question. I cannot get your second solution working - the string is not found.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Forgot to add the -E option. Have a try now.
If possible add some sample. Interestingly, -w option works with spaces also, just tested that.

Comment: That's weird. May be the test data set I'm using is not appropriate. Please add a sample file along with the string you searched for, and your problem will be solved ASAP.

Comment: Apparently we have multiple `grep` versions. When I used the correct one it (the `hasMatch` second solution) worked perfectly. Thanks!